# How to find if somewhere Jquery is disabling anchor tag within html

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I do have some code containing anchor tag within li elements and when I click I remain on the same page and when I right click and open link in new tab then it work's fine. If I replace an anchor tag on any corner of the web page it works but doesn't works within a div  Is there any solution for the same tried setting z-index but no use. Here is the code..

```
<div class="side-banner" style="width:288px; float:left;height:auto; z-index:1001;">
    <div id="menu" style="float:left; width:auto;height:auto;">
        <nav id="nav" style="width:auto; height:auto;z-index:1000">
            <h2><i class="fa fa-reorder"></i>All Categories</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>
                      //This Link doesn't works
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Create")"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>Organizer</a>
                    <h2><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i>Organizer</h2>                        
                </li>
                <li>
                     //This doesn't works
                    <a href="/Home/Index"><i class="fa fa-book"></i>Project Info</a>
                    <h2><i class="fa fa-book"></i>Project Info</h2>                        
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Human Resource</a>
                    <h2><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Human Resource</h2>

                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Collections</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Credits</a>
    //Now this link works fine
    @Html.ActionLink("Create","Create")
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
        </div>        
    <div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: Any chance you could replace the code with what is generated in the browser?

Comment: @JamieBarker plz find the the html along with jquery @ http://jsfiddle.net/Zaker/jxdpccef/  .Thanks

Comment: @JamieBarker plz comment if anything unclear

Comment: @JamieBarker any clue

Comment: Sorry, been eating my lunch! Will have a look now :)

Comment: On your fiddle, could you replace the HTML with the generated HTML in the browser. Just to remove the .Net code

Comment: @JamieBarker plz have a look here. http://jsfiddle.net/Zaker/c1y0nnpn/. It is here as you described. Thanks

Comment: Which links in particular are not working?

Comment: @JamieBarker all the links doesn't work . Except the one which is out of all the div's. Since I just wanted to check I place a link outside the divs and only this particular div worked and rest behaves useless. Thanks for your comments

Comment: Well, nearly every link (like, 95% of them) has a "#" in the href... with this it is expected for links not go anywhere. Are you talking about these?

Comment: @JamieBarker the ones which have the links within the anchor tag for example <a href="/Home/Create">New Employee</a> Now this doesn't works

Comment: @JamieBarker I have update the post. Plz check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69820/discussion-between-jamie-barker-and-user).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isDefaultPrevented()` to check if a links default action has been prevented by jquery.

So if somewhere you have something like:

```
$('a.someLink').click(function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault(); // stops the link working
});
```

This would stop the link from working as normal (linking to a url)

```
isDefaultPrevented() returns true/false if an event has been stopped. i.e.

$('a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.isDefaultPrevented(); // returns true
});
```

You'd need to look at what/how/when you are potentially disabling links, then bind to some `a` tags and check if those events have been stopped
(if you post your javascript we might be able to suggest further)

here is a demo of how you'd check if the default had been prevented on a link somewhere else

```
<a id='myLink' href='http://facebook.com'>link</a>


$(function (){
    // lets say you've bound events some where
    $('#myLink').click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });


    // somewhere else in the code you can bind to all `a` tags and test
    // if the default has been prevented

    $('a').click(function (e) {
        alert(e.isDefaultPrevented());
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now if I write the two lines at the bottom of my code and click any link then I am getting false in the alert box. So anyhow  I still stand where I were. But isn't that one thing is clear that jquery is not disabling any anchor tag because any anchor tag I click I get false in the alert. So what's next . Thanks again for your approach.